# How to move Cloth down when it reaches end of table in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics, unity3d-editor, cloth-simulation

I have a sewing machine and a hanger-stand. I have a plane to which i have assigned cloth component.

Now what i want to achieve is Move the plane on table of sewing machine, When start of cloth reaches end of table the cloth should start dropping down where the hanger is located now when the other end of cloth reaches the table end it should drop on opposite side of the hanger as we hang cloth in hanger.

Now how to achieve all this?
Solution I have applied was to removed gravity and added 0.1 external acceleration to plane cloth component so it moves on the table. Problem to solve is turning it down when it reaches end of table and hanging on hanger?